# Imprimir variable en un archivo php

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy intentando imprimir una variable que contiene la hora y fecha la cual digito desde en un modulo especifico, pero no he podido, hasta el momento tengo que ingresar directamente al archivo `js` para hacer el cambio.

**Este es el modulo para el cliente**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Este seria el módulo de administrador.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
var countDownDate = new Date("Oct 29, 2022 24:00:00").getTime();

var x = setInterval(function() {

    var now = new Date().getTime();
    var distance = countDownDate - now;
    
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + " Dias | " + hours + " Horas | " +
        minutes + " Minutos | " + seconds + " Segundos | ";

    if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Flash Promo finalizada";
    }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1sCRPdkRXhBV2PBLUdRb4tMg1w2YPf37qatUFeS7zlBy7jJI8Lf4VHwWfZZfpXtYSLy85pkm9GaYVYMfw5BC1A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Admin</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Panel administrativo</h1>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1" class="form-label">Alcance de la promoción</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3"></textarea>
    </div>

    <script src="js/hora.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Si sustituyes `id="exampleFormControlTextarea1"` por `id="demo"` te va a funcionar perfectamente...

Comment: suponiendo que lo que quieres es obtener la fecha que guardas en un php para recuperarla en el js que genera la dinamica de la hora minuto segundo.
usa bases de datos así es como se hace. lo guardas en la base y después recupeas en el html para incorporarlo al js de esa pagina.

Answer (score 1):

Faltan algunos detalles en tu pregunta, por ejemplo, cómo traes la fecha desde el panel de administración? Es desde una base de datos?

De ser así, puedes guardar la fecha en un campo oculto en la vista del cliente y obtener el `value` desde `JS` o simplemente desde `JS` puedes obtener la fecha a través de la API `fetch`. *Esa tarea te la dejo ya que desconozco el contexto de tu proyecto*.

Por lo demás, estás bien encaminado.

```js
//Obtener el value del textarea
var fechaFinal = document.getElementById("fechaFinal").value;
//El resto de tu función
var countDownDate = new Date(fechaFinal).getTime();

var x = setInterval(function() {

  var now = new Date().getTime();
  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + " Dias | " + hours + " Horas | " + minutes + " Minutos | " + seconds + " Segundos | ";

  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Flash Promo finalizada";
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1sCRPdkRXhBV2PBLUdRb4tMg1w2YPf37qatUFeS7zlBy7jJI8Lf4VHwWfZZfpXtYSLy85pkm9GaYVYMfw5BC1A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
  />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>User</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Vista de usuario</h1>
  <div class="mb-3">
    <!-- Aquí tienes el textarea oculto con la fecha de finalización -->
    <textarea class="form-control" id="fechaFinal" rows="3" hidden>
      Oct 29, 2022 24:00:00
    </textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="demo" class="form-label">Quedan</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="demo" rows="3"></textarea>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Muy valiosa tu respuesta, ¿Pero en caso contrario como puedo editar el campo de hora y fecha en el modulo administrativo y mostrarlo al cliente? Gracias!

Comment: Lo único que se me ocurre es que almacenes o edites la fecha en una base de datos desde el módulo administrativo y desde el cliente haces la consulta a la base de datos para traer la fecha. Si necesitas detalles de cómo hacerlo, te sugiero que investigues primero cómo almacenar datos desde `PHP` en una BD y cómo consultarlos. Posteriormente, puedes regresar a StackOverflow si tienes dudas puntuales ya que no podemos darte todo el código sin conocer el contexto de tu proyecto. No sabemos si ya tienes la base de datos o cómo almacenas y consultas la fecha.